# Need help remembering title of 80s-era sci fi anime featuring car combat with Star Wars inspired characters

Tags: story-identification, anime

Been trying to track down some of my old favorites from the 80s era of anime, one that has refused to show up in search after search has brought me here with the hope that someone might know of it.

Details:
Sci-fi anime series (viewed on American TV early weekday mornings) during the 80s. Heroes drove cars and enemies were cars, with the heroic cars being high-tech and each unique, and enemies being some organic spore-based grow-on-demand instant cars. One of the latter had a bola style weapon, forget the others.

Characters were quite obviously modelled after Star Wars 4, I forget what their cars were capable of except in one case:

-"Han" owned the starship they traveled on, "Luke" was main character (?), "Ben" and "Leia" rode in the same car, which had a drill for going underground.

As far as what year the title was aired, I can't say for certain, around the mid 80s I can say confidently.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is it possible you're thinking of the 1985 French/North American animation, *[Jayce and the Wheeled Warriors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jayce_and_the_Wheeled_Warriors)*?

[image: Show logo]

> The series follows protagonists Jayce, Flora, Herc Stormsailor, Oon, and Gillian in their search for Jayce's father Audric. Meanwhile, they are opposing the main antagonist Saw Boss and his followers, the Monster Minds. Audric was a botanist who performed experiments with biotechnology, one experiment creating Flora. In another experiment, Audric attempted to create a plant that could prevent starvation. But when he succeeded, a nearby star exploded into a supernova. The radiation from the supernova's explosion changed the plant and four others into the Monster Minds: a race of plant-like extraterrestrials who wished to conquer the universe. Audric created a root that could destroy the Monster Minds, but was forced to flee before he could complete the task, after which the Monster Minds made Audric's laboratory their headquarters. Audric kept half of the root himself and gave the other half to his servant, the Eternal Squire Oon, whom he sent to serve Jayce. Jayce and his friends are thereafter on a quest to find Audric and form the complete root.

The enemies were indeed derived from plant spores. While the vehicles were driven by any member of the team

> **Drill Sergeant** - Drill Sergeant is a two-seater vehicle with a drill to dig tunnels. It is also equipped with two pop-out guns in the front of the cab. It is driven in the opening sequence by Flora.

For the bolos, you might be thinking of [Flingshot](http://www.wheelies.net/wwuniverse/wwthings/LLvehicles.html):
[image: Flingshot]

> Though Armed Force and the rest of the original Lightning League vehicles support a wide range of weaponry, they are not well suited to heavy artillery. Fling Shot was built to fill this role. The disk-launcher/catapult on this vehicle allows explosive photon disks and other projectiles to be fired at long range. The vehicle is also protected by a double compliment of armor. It can withstand more enemy fire than any of the other Lightning League vehicles, yet is still small and light enough to be maneuverable in battle.

The Wikipedia article notes (italic emphasis mine):

> **Herc Stormsailor** - A mercenary who is the proud owner and pilot of the space barge The Pride Of The Skies II. He used to have a close relationship with Pirate Queen Morgana and it is implied he once was a member of the Pirate Guild. He was once an intergalactic commando before he quit. *He was largely modeled after Han Solo*.

Gillian, the wizard adviser, fits for Ben, which would also make sense since he and Flora are listed as the usual pilots for Drill Sergeant. Jayce, as the main protagonist with a missing father, would be playing the Luke role.

Here is the intro:

Comment: If this turns out to be the one, don't forget to click on the check mark by the voting buttons to accept. :) I had one of these cats as a kid, although I only ever saw an episode or two of the series.

Comment: Man, this brings back memories!

Comment: Thanks! That lays to rest a long standing mystery for me, cheers, and much appreciated!